# Getting current selected text from wysihtml5 editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

Recently, I have worked with wysihtml5 Editor but I am not able to get the selected text of the Editor. Using JQuery I have written this code snippet but it  is not working.

```
var len = $("#ticketmessage").val().length;
            var start = $("#ticketmessage")[0].selectionStart;
            var end = $("#ticketmessage")[0].selectionEnd;
            var sel = $("#ticketmessage").val().substring(start, end);
```

Thanks & Regards

Manisha Biswas

Comment: Provide a JSFiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `getSelection` method of the global `window` object? This is used to get the currently selected (highlighted) text on the page, e.g:

```
var text = window.getSelection().toString();
```

Alternatively, you might need to use the `Range` interface to get the selected text, e.g:

```
var text = document.selection.createRange().text;
```

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text) for some examples of use

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
  self.editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("my-editor", {
      parserRules: wysihtml5ParserRules,
      useLineBreaks: true,
      stylesheets: [self.editorCss]
    });

 var selection = new wysihtml5.Selection(self.editor);
 var selectedText = selection.editor.composer.selection.getText();
```